# jquery dialog, open a link in the same dialog window

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

I have a link in a dialog modal window. I need this link to show in the same DIALOG MODAL window where it is.

Here's how my link looks like, it is formed in a php file and then passed to the html template:

```
$link = "<a href='mypage.php?f=dosomething&param1=".$var1."&param2=".$var2."' id='dosomething' >Need to open this link in the same dialog window</a>";
```

And here's my jquery code:

```
  $("#dosomething").dialog(
            { autoOpen:false,
              modal:true,
              overlay: { opacity: 0.8, background: "black" },
              width:850,
              height:650,
              title:"A title",
              draggable:true,
              hide:"slow",
              closeOnEscape: true
            }); 
            $("#dosomething").dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$link = "<a href='mypage.php?f=dosomething&param1=".$var1."&param2=".$var2."' id='dosomething' onclick="loadurl();" >Need to open this link in the same dialog window</a>";

$(document).ready(function(){

   function loadurl(){
   $("html").load("mypage.php?f=dosomething&param1=".$var1."&param2=".$var2."")
   }


})
```

Comment: adding php variables to a jquery function?

Comment: @user523129 i don't know what are they..I am just showing how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property

```
 target="_self"
```

to your hyperlink

```
<a href src="http://google.com" target="_self">Open google in same window<a>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it opens the link in the parent window, not in the dialog

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery to open the href of the link in the same dialog, use something like this:

your link:

```
$link = "<a href='mypage.php?f=dosomething&param1=".$var1."&param2=".$var2."' id='dosomething' onclick="loadurl();" >Need to open this link in the same dialog window</a>";
```

and the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dosomething").click(function() {
        $("#yourcontainer").load($(this).attr("href"));
        return false;
    });
});
```

this would print the result into a container with the id "yourcontainer". So, that means if your dialog has "mydialog" as its id, the code row would look like $("#mydialog").... instead of $("#yourcontainer")....

But if you want to simply open the link in the same window, use the a attribute

```
target="_self"
```

Comment: I'm afraid it opens the link in the parent window, not in the dialog

Comment: oh, I forgot to add the following:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dosomething").click(function() {
        $("#yourcontainer").load($(this).attr("href"));
        return false;  
    });
});

it should return false as well. So if your dialog has the id of "mydialog" you can just put #mydialog instead of #yourcontainer. (Edited my answer as well)